# Slax don't init from HDD

Tags: debian, boot, hard-disk

I installed Slax version 9.11.0 on a Positivo Mobo S7 netbook. If I boot Slax SO from USB, the Slax init correctly, but if I boot the same system from HDD the system init in text mode and the following error occurs:

> **Fatal error occurred - Could not locate slax data**
>   Something went wrong and we can't continue. This should never happen.
>   Please reboot your computer with Ctrl+Alt+delete ...

Where's the problem and how to fix my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slax is a distribution designed primarily for USB-based installations, but it can be copied to the HDD also. If you followed [Slax's instructions](https://www.slax.org/starting.php), there should be a directory named `slax` at the root directory of your HDD. You should verify that any files there have not been damaged: compare them to the corresponding files on the USB. If you find that a large file in that directory on the HDD is smaller than a corresponding file on the USB, the problem might be that the file on the HDD has been damaged somehow, and you could try replacing it with a fresh copy from the USB.

In the `slax` directory, there might also be a `changes` sub-directory. It will contain your files and any changes you've made to the standard configuration of Slax. Any files in this directory should not be replaced.

At the end of the webpage I linked above, there is a list of Slax boot parameters (known as "cheatcodes" in Slax terminology). When trying to boot Slax from the HDD, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> when you see the Slax boot menu, then type in `debug` and press Enter. That should make the system give you more detailed messages about what it's trying to do and what might be going wrong.

Comment: The prompt keep failing on boot, but it throws some times this message: "find_data_try memory/data"and some "echo" commands with "READ" and "WRITE"